# Using Laravel 5.4 query builder with an array (json serialized) attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm stumped on this one. I can search an array of ids but I want to search the reverse. I have models with lists of ids as "with_ids" attribute and want to search similar to mongo db where id is in that array of ids.
   For example

```
db.conversations.find( { with_ids: { $in: [id] } } )
```

How do I do that with Laravel and mysql/Eloquent?

```
$conversations = Conversation::with('messages.user')->where('with_ids', $id)->orWhere('created_by', $id)->get();
```

it's the where('with_ids', $id) I can't figure out... Any suggestions??

**To clarify further:**
I need to find if the user is participating in other conversations as well as the ones he created. The with_ids is a json serialized array f.ex [1,2,23,12] how do i search inside the array attribute?

Comment: I think your query should work the way it is. What does it return?

Comment: Blank array... nothing Conversation::with('messages.user')->where('with_ids', $id)->get();

Comment: oh wait. Where is 'with_ids' ? in conversation or in messages?

Comment: In conversation. It's between created_by and with_ids are the users participating

Comment: What does ` Conversation::with('messages.user')->get();` return? All the conversation with all the users involved?

Comment: All conversations in the DB with respective messages and their user attached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137605/discussion-between-eddythedove-and-iamlasse).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand. Did you try with `whereIn()`;

```
$conversations = Conversation::with('messages.user')
->whereIn('with_ids', [$id])
->orWhere('created_by', $id)
->get();
```

**Edit**

```
$conversations = Conversation::with('messages.user', function($query) {
    $query->where('id', $id); // user_id ?
})
->orWhere('created_by', $id)
->get();
```

Comment: I need it the other way arround. I have an id i need to check if it exists in the list of ids "with_ids" I need to find if the user is participating in other conversations as well as the ones he created. e.g. the with_ids is a list of user ids. with_ids is a json serialized array f.ex [1,2,23,12] how do i search inside the array attribute?

Comment: Did you at least give this a try. Please do and lets' see.

Answer (score 0):

After MUCH digging I finally found a solution. FIND_IN_SET in a whereRaw query did the trick. In case anyone else has come upon this issue, hope it helps.

it's not pretty because for some reason quotes need to be stripped out

```
Conversation::where('created_by', $id)->orWhereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(?, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(with_ids, '\"', ''), '[', ''), ']','')) > 0", $id)->get()
```

That's the final query to get aggregated conversations where user either created or is part of.